# Chrome JavaScript Slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am having trouble with a slider I am trying to build. Basically, it auto scrolls through the images just fine, however the next and previous arrows have no effect at all.

I get this error when Next is clicked -

**Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined gallery.js:48
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined**

Here is the fiddle link -
http://jsfiddle.net/8L5xA/

But here is my Html and JS -

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">


    <div id="slider">
        <Img id="1" src="images/slide1.jpg">
        <Img id="2" src="images/slide 2.jpg">
        <Img id="3" src="images/slide 3.jpg">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="left" onclick="prev(); return false;">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="right" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>


    </div>



    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is JS

```
sliderInt=1;
sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
    $(".right").click(function(){
       next(); 
    });
     $(".left").click(function(){
       next(); 
    });
});

 var count=0;

function startSlider(){
    count=$("#slider>Img").size();

    loop=setInterval(function(){

        if(sliderNext>count){
            sliderNext=1;
            sliderInt=1;
        }

        $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
        $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt=sliderNext;
        sliderNext=sliderNext + 1;

    },3000);

}

function prev(){
    newSlide=sliderInt-1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next(){
    newSlide=sliderInt + 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function showSlide(){
    if(id>count){
        id=1;
    }else if(id<1){
        id=count;
    }

    $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
    $("#slider>Img#" + id).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt=id;
    sliderNext=id + 1;

}
```

I am only a beginner and any help would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were lot of logically errors in your code, i have tuned it here

**CODE:**

```
 sliderInt = 1;
 sliderNext = 2;
 var count = 0;
 var loop;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
    $(".right").click(function (event) {
     //alert("clicked next");
      next();
      event.preventDefault();
   });
   $(".left").click(function (event) {
     prev();
     event.preventDefault();
   });
});



function startSlider() {
 count = $("#slider>Img").size();
 delayCall();

}

 function delayCall() {
  loop = setInterval(function () {

    if (sliderNext > count) {
        sliderNext = 1;
        sliderInt = 1;
    }

    $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
    $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

  }, 3000);

   }

 function prev() {
   // alert("previous");
   clearInterval(loop);
   if (sliderInt == 1) newSlide = count;
   else newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
   showSlide(newSlide);
 }

 function next() {
   // alert(sliderInt+":"+count);
   clearInterval(loop);
   if (sliderInt == count) sliderInt = 0;
      newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
      showSlide(newSlide);
 }

 function showSlide(id) {
    //  alert(id+":"+count);
   /* if(id>count){
       id=1;
      }else{
      id;
   }*/

  $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
 $("#slider>Img#" + id).fadeIn(300).delay(1000);

  //Thread.sleep(3000);
  sliderInt = id;
  sliderNext = id + 1;
  delayCall();

 }
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/8L5xA/4/

Your code had nothing to do with Chrome browser, just the logic was wrong that's it. i have verified this  code on Firefox 25.0 and on Chrome 30.0.1599.101 and its working smoothly, hope this solves your problem.

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: Thank you so much :D Like i said earlier I am new to this so hopefully I will have these mistakes less often. Typical that after 7 hours of trying to figure out what is up, you answered it easily.

Comment: Syntax is not a tough thing  buddy when creating a application, all that you should know is the right logic . anyway all the best with your application :)

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
showSlide(newSlide);
```

you pass the int newSlide, 
but on the function definition, you do not catch any arguments.

Change

```
function showSlide(){
```

to

```
function showSlide(id){
```

Hope this helps